# How to fire an event when the user leaves certain web pages?

Tags: javascript, html

In my project, I have a server and several html pages linked to one another with a tags and my index.html is a page where the user goes to login to my server.

My pages are index.html(the login), home.html(the main page), statistics.html(a page where a logged user can see information from my server in table format) and notifs.html(where a logged user can see an history of the past notifications done by my server).

When an user wants to log in, a request is sent to my server to log in the user and I get an JSON with the user's account info in response that I store in localstorage and when the user logs out, a request is sent to log them out and I delete the object from localstorage.

If an user is not logged in, they are redirected to index.html no matter the page from the ones mentioned above they are in.

My problem is: I need to log out the user whenever they leave any of the html pages of my project on a certain manner
(if they leave the page but go to another of my pages, they shouldn't be logged out but if they go somewhere else on the same window, like to www.google.com for example or when the window is closed, then they should be logged out) but the beforeunload event, where the user is logged out, fires when the user leaves the page but it doesn't distinguish between if the destination is one of my pages or if it is another page or if the window is closed and because of that the user is logged out if they try to go to another of the pages of my project.

Up until now, I have found no way of telling if they are going to another page of my project or in another page or if the window is being closed... I always end up with answers saying that I should use the beforeunload event and give a warning before the user leaves the page instead of logging them out but if the user suddenly ignores for whatever reason the warning then my web application will have to depend on if the JSON with the information of the account in localstorage still exists, otherwise that user won't be able to log in again and I want to prevent that.

This is the code used in order to log out an user and I put it in all of the scripts of the pages except in the one of index.html.
(The redirect parameter is true when the function logoutAccount is called by its dedicated button but if it is called by the beforeunload event, then redirect is false because the user shouldn't go back to the login page (in this case index.html) because they should still be logged in if they go to one of the pages of my project.)

```
function logoutAccount(redirect) {
    if(localStorage['loggedAccount']){
        var account=JSON.parse(localStorage['loggedAccount']);
        var logoutRequest=new XMLHttpRequest();
        logoutRequest.open('GET',url+"/logout/"+account.id,false);
        logoutRequest.send(null);
        localStorage.removeItem('loggedAccount');
        if(redirect){
            window.location.replace("index.html");
        }
    }else{
        if(redirect){
            window.location.replace("index.html");
        }
    }
}

document.getElementById("logoutButton").addEventListener("click",function () {
    logoutAccount(true);
});

$(window).on("beforeunload", function() {
    logoutAccount(false);
});
```

As I described before, this will cause the user to log out whenever they leave the page even if they are going to another of the pages of my project which is not the result I want.

And this is the code that allows an user to log in which is in the script of index.html:

```
function onLogin () {
    var username = document.getElementById('username');
    var password = document.getElementById('password');
    var data = {};
    data.userName = username.value;
    data.passWord = password.value;
    if(localStorage["AccountTokent"]){
        data.token = localStorage["AccountTokent"];
        localStorage.removeItem("AccountTokent");
    }else{
        data.token="some random generated text";
    }


    var json = JSON.stringify(data);

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if(xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            localStorage.setItem('loggedAccount',xhr.responseText);
            window.location.replace("home.html");
        } else if (xhr.status === 401) {
            alert("Wrong password or username");
        }
    };

    xhr.open('POST', url + "/login", false);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
    xhr.send(json);
}
```

So as long as the user is logged in and is on one of the pages of my project, their account should still be logged in.

If they leave from home.html ,for example, to www.google.com then they are logged out, which is fine but if they leave from home.html to notifs.html then they are logged out and redirected to index.html, which is what I want to prevent.

Comment: At each redirect you could wait for a set amount of time (few seconds) and if the user isn't on your page anymore you log him out. You can either do this on the backend (hard but more consistent) or by putting a timestamp into the localStorage when he is redirecting and only accepting his logged-in state if it the time-stamp is x seconds old.

Comment: @MixT4PE so if I well understood your idea of putting a timestamp into localstorage, I would have to put a timestamp in localstorage on the event beforeunload(or before each time I use window.location.replace())  and then when the user leaves to a page from my project, I check if the timestamp is there and if it is x seconds old and if it isn't, then the person is logged out. Is that it?

Comment: Yes that's about what I suggested. You might as well say "not logged in" because the authentication he provides (localStorage) is "invalid" by your checks (more than x seconds old)